# jquery modal doesnt works in mozilla

Tags: jquery

it doesnt work in mozilla, it does work in chrome and IE... whats happening here..

`$('#myModal').modal('show');`

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Daftar Proyek</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div id="proyeklist"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

any suggestion?

Comment: create a demo the reproduces this